# Why is this question still closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Question: [Baby distressed by one parent](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/41374/baby-distressed-by-one-parent)

The comments only indicate "why is the child so distressed by the presence of this other parent" as a missing detail and that is addressed by the second edit. What other details are desired?

A comment by a moderator says "They went to a professional and they couldn't help", but didn't explain why the professional's help is relevant to the question that is actually asked, or any other details that might be missing in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You have not rectified the problems with the question:

- It is still likely to elicit opinion
- there are multiple questions
- there is still a lack of detail

I think those first two are major problems - the help pages give good guidance on this.

Comment: Can you spell out 1) how is the question likely to elicit opinion 2) if you consider the three questions posed are not related and can be split 3) what other details are desired?

Comment: “Is it valid…?” Will get opinions.

Comment: I edited that out, is it OK now?